# CISCO VPN ubuntu 14.04

Tags: vpn, cisco

My VPN connection has suddenly failed. It was working fine last week but this week it just refuses to start. I checked the syslog using:

```
$ less /var/log/syslog | grep NetworkManager
```

and i receive the following output:

```
Apr 22 12:14:48 GLaDOS NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN service 'vpnc' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.vpnc), PID 3906
Apr 22 12:14:48 GLaDOS NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN service 'vpnc' appeared; activating connections
Apr 22 12:15:09 GLaDOS NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
Apr 22 12:15:09 GLaDOS NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN connection 'VPN connection 1' (Connect) reply received.
Apr 22 12:15:09 GLaDOS NetworkManager[739]: SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Apr 22 12:15:09 GLaDOS NetworkManager[739]: SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Apr 22 12:15:09 GLaDOS NetworkManager[739]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Apr 22 12:15:09 GLaDOS NetworkManager[739]: SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Apr 22 12:15:09 GLaDOS NetworkManager[739]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Apr 22 12:15:09 GLaDOS NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
Apr 22 12:15:09 GLaDOS NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Apr 22 12:15:09 GLaDOS NetworkManager[739]: <info> Policy set 'Wired connection 1' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Apr 22 12:15:09 GLaDOS NetworkManager[739]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Apr 22 12:15:15 GLaDOS NetworkManager[739]: <info> VPN service 'vpnc' disappeared
```

I've tried to follow a couple of repairs for this but nothing seems to be working. Any help would be really appreciated.

Edit: I have all of the relevant packages installed:
/etc/NetworkManager/VPN/nm-vpnc-service.name;
/etc/dbus-1/system.d/nm-vpnc-service.conf;
/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-vpnc-service;
/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-vpnc-service-vpnc-helper;
/usr/share/doc/network-manager-vpnc/AUTHORS;
/usr/share/doc/network-manager-vpnc/NEWS.gz;
/usr/share/doc/network-manager-vpnc/changelog.Debian.gz;
/usr/share/doc/network-manager-vpnc/copyright.

and all of the relevant dependencies also:
libc6 (>= 2.4); 
libdbus-glib-1-2 (>= 0.78); 
libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3); 
libnm-glib-vpn1 (>= 0.7.999); 
libnm-util2 (>= 0.8.998); 
vpnc.

I have also confirmed the following:

'NetworkManager now assigns IP address 127.0.1.1 to the local nameserver process that it controls instead of 127.0.0.1. If the system's /etc/resolv.conf is absent or is a static file instead of the symbolic link to ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf installed by default then this static file will have to be updated by the administrator in order to continue using the NetworkManager-controlled nameserver.'